# brew install memcached - easy, but where is the config file?

Tags: macos, command-line

I've installed memcached on osx 10.9 using brew. I want to change default settings, but where does brew look for config file and what is the name?

I tried to put it here /usr/local/etc/memcached.conf but it didn't like it.

So where?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/memcached/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
vi /usr/local/opt/memcached/*.plist
```

plist file is an xml that contains all the options for memcached.

modify as needed and than:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
```

Comment: follow this up with `brew services restart memcached`, and `echo stats | nc 127.0.0.1 11211` to check if your changes have worked